# Need to stop AVPlayer before playing new stream

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have On-line Radio app. Located on the first viewController (tableView) audio streams. Audio streams are made as a table. By clicking on the name of the stream screen opens with AVpalyer. The problem is that when opening the second stream, the ашкые stream is played simultaneously. How to make so that would be played if one thread, and the second was turned down?

avplayer:

```
@interface RadioViewController ()

@end

@implementation RadioViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSString *restorationId = self.restorationIdentifier;
NSString *streamId = _detail.label;
NSString* identifer = [restorationId stringByAppendingString: streamId];
NSLog(@"%@", identifer);


self.title = apptitle;
self.streamLabel.text = _detail.label;
//Определение потока

NSString *streamURL;

if (_detail.label == @"ПЕРВЫЙ"){
    streamURL = streamURLpervyj;
} if (_detail.label == @"РОК") {
    streamURL = streamURLrok;
} if (_detail.label == @"БИТ") {
    streamURL = streamURLbit;
} if (_detail.label == @"ПО-РУССКИ") {
    streamURL = streamURLporusski;
} if (_detail.label == @"ХИП-ХОП") {
    streamURL = streamURLhiphop;
} if (_detail.label == @"РЕЛАКС") {
    streamURL = streamURLrelax;
} if (_detail.label == @"РЕТРО") {
    streamURL = streamURLretro;
}

    if(![self connected]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Невозможно установить соединение" message:@"Проверьте соединение с интернетом" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ОК" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        //Start stream
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL]];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        music = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        [music play];
    }


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playButton:)
                                             name:@"TogglePlayPause"
                                           object:nil];

//Set Title View
titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, myScrollView.frame.size.width, 40)];
[self setStyle]; //Set style layers
titleView.text = @"Подключаюсь...";
CGFloat textLength = titleView.intrinsicContentSize.width;
[myScrollView addSubview: titleView];
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
if (textLength < 240) {
    [self centerText];
}

 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self   selector:@selector(timed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 }
```

http://dev.b4u.by/radio.jpg

Comment: You need to stop the current radio from playing by calling `pause` on your instance of `AVPlayer` before starting playing the new stream.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. 
I can not understand in what way to do it.

Comment: Just before the if where you check the connection , call `[music pause];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamViewController.h

```
@interface APStreamsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
{   
    AVPlayer *musicSegue;
}
```

StreamViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
if (indexPath) {
    APStreamsData *item = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:item];
}
    RadioViewController *music = [segue destinationViewController];
    [music setMusic: musicSegue];
}
```

RadioViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVPlayer *music;
```

And in RadioViewController change music to _music )))

Answer (score 0):

You can decleare avplayer object "music" in your appdelegate then access it by this way

```
AppDelegate *mainDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[mainDelegate.music pause];
mainDelegate.music = nil;
```

when you want to start new stream or before alloc init

Comment: I do not know much English, but I'll try to explainI do not know much English, but I'll try to explain.
Must I to transfer of avplayer controller all code to the delegate controller and delegate music?

Comment: no you dont need to move all code to app delegate just move the declearation of avplayer object to app delegate

Comment: in StreamsViewController.h [AVPlayer *music;]
in StreamsViewController.m 
[- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

 NSString *streamURL = @"sdfsdfsdf";
 AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL]];
            [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
            music = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
  AppDelegate *mainDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[mainDelegate.music pause];
mainDelegate.music = nil;
}

Comment: And stil not working (

I declearate avplayer and music in StreamsViewController

How can i delegate music?

Comment: what is you problem now? please give me the current code